# Installing a PCI-E graphics card when the onboard VGA port is not working

Tags: graphics-card, vga

Previously I had asked a question abt monitor/VGA port problems.
Today finally i came to a conclusion that the VGA port on my motherboard is broken.

The solution is find is to buy a PCI-E VGA card , a cheaper option.

OR

Buy a Graphics Card, I prefer this one as VGA Card manufacturers aren't quite standard.

I want to know if the graphic cards we get today are plug and play? Should I disble the onboard VGA port before installing a Graphics card. If the VGA port isnt working in the first place (the monitor wont start) how should i do it ? All i need is how to install a Graphics card when the onboard VGA port isnt working.

Also suggest me a graphics card, I just need a Port for my monitor, I dont need high performance.

Answer (score 1):

Depends, usually the bios will be set-up to use the PCI-E as an override, so you will be able to plug in the Graphics card and attach a monitor and it will work. You will not have the best resolution until the correct drivers have been installed for the card, so install once Windows boots.

If you have set you bios to only run from the onboard graphics and you cannot get the bios on your monitor, refer to your motherboard manual in regards to resetting you bios as the defaults should allow for the detection of the PCI-E card.

Comment: My thoughts exactly. You should be able to reset the CMOS/BIOS with a jumper or something on the motherboard, and if the motherboard manufacturers are sane in the slightest, it will default to overriding the onboard adapter when a card is installed. If the motherboard doesn't do that simple, logical action for some reason, then it is clearly pretty bad and likely to have other problems so you are best off just getting a new board, even a used one.

Answer (score 0):

After troubleshooting a computer you find out that the onboard video card adapter is damaged.After replacing it when you turned on the computer everything works but the screen is blank what do you do

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).